# How to include/require a php file in php file on bluehost server

Tags: php, require, internal-server-error, server-side-includes

I have tried all below even try to use require but nothing works.

```
<?PHP include "myfile.php"; ?>
<?PHP include "/myfile.php"; ?>
<?PHP include "./myfile.php"; ?>
<?PHP include(__DIR__,"myfile.php"); ?>
<?PHP include "/public_html/myfile.php"; ?>
```

All my files are on blue host server and whenever it comes at the point where the object is created from `myfile.php` (which is in public_html directory) it gives `[01-Sep-2015 20:56:07 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/MyConnection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear:/home1/user/public_html') in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 29
[01-Sep-2015 20:56:07 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyConnection' not found in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 32`.

I have debugged my code every statement works perfectly okay unless or until is not related to the `myfile.php` and also this code works perfectly okay on my wampp server with the local files. Any help will extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `status 500` meaning that the issue is with the file itself?

Comment: Could also run a syntax check on the file...or try accessing directly from command line. @PaulCrovella has the right idea, it has to have produced an error.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my computer (local) and includes the file in the php page but it doesn't work here. Thanks for replying fellows

Answer (score 1):

As Paul said in the comments, you need to consult the error log anytime you get a 500 error with PHP.

However, you're using absolute paths when you prefix with / and I am 99% certain that you shouldn't be.

```
<?PHP include "/myfile.php"; ?>
```

This means you're actually trying to read myfile.php from the `/` directory of the server.  This isn't the same as using the web root directory with HTML.

You should be using relative paths or using the full absolute path.  Note that `__DIR__` does NOT have a directory separator suffix in most cases (unless it is the root directory).

```
<?PHP include(__DIR__,"myfile.php"); ?>
```

Needs to be:

```
<?PHP include(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "myfile.php"); ?>
```

You can also modify the include path.  Resort to documentation on get_include_path and set_include_path.

Comment: `<?PHP include(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "myfile.php"); ?>` doesn't even work, it actually didn't load the whole page.

Comment: Do some debugging then, check your error log, print out `(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "myfile.php")`

Comment: I have done the debugging and it shows that anything related to including the file causes trouble, rest is perfectly fine.

Comment: it doesn't load the contents of the page when I use `(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "myfile.php")` and log only says that `[01-Sep-2015 11:10:33 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home1/domain/public_html/myfile.php on line 25`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the absolute path

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myfile.php"); ?>
```

Comment: It behaved same as the above mentioned code in the question. :(

Comment: Gives an error `[01-Sep-2015 21:26:05 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pageState in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 13
[01-Sep-2015 21:26:09 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home1/user/public_html/includefile.php on line 3`

Comment: This one actually worked, i figured there was a problem in my code at some place. i was calling a function using this but I didn't use dollar sign ($) with it

Answer (score 0):

Use

`<?PHP include "var/www/public_html/myfile.php";`

Comment: This works as it is the absolute path to the file being included

Comment: Check permission of file..should be 755

Comment: Try and include a different file present in the root. If that works delete the file and upload the fresh one

Comment: the problem is that, it isn't including any file by using about statements on the sever but it works perfectly fine on my wampp or localhost.

Comment: Edit your question and post the details along with the file structure.

Comment: I have elaborated my question and `myfile.php` and `index.php` is in the same directory.

Comment: Give an error `[01-Sep-2015 21:21:51 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pageState in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 13
[01-Sep-2015 21:21:53 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'var/www/public_html/includefile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear:/home1/user/public_html') in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 26`

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I have a file (init.php) that gets included in each file in the site that detects the path of where it is on the server and saves it to a constant to be used when including other files. I always put the init.php file in the root of the website.

```
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){ define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); }
include( ABSPATH . 'filename.php');
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives same output as `<?PHP include "filename.php"; ?>`

Comment: Give an error `[01-Sep-2015 21:18:10 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pageState in /home1/user/public_html/myfile.php on line 13
[01-Sep-2015 21:18:13 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home1/user/public_html/includefile.php on line 3`